# How to print the "to be executed" @Test method's name in "@BeforeEach" method in JUnit 5?

Tags: junit5

I understand we can do this in JUnit 4 using `@Rule` and `TestName` however am using JUnit 5 (Jupiter) and am struggling to find a way to print the test methods(to be executed) name in `@BeforeEach` method.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Declare a [`TestInfo`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInfo) parameter in your `@BeforeEach` method. JUnit Jupiter will inject an instance of it at runtime containing all the available information related to the "currently executed test".

For example like this:

```
@BeforeEach
void init(TestInfo testInfo) {
    String displayName = testInfo.getDisplayName();
    String methodName = testInfo.getTestMethod().orElseThrow().getName();
    // ...
}
```

For more details see https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dependency-injection