# Pulling in a junit test method name from an extended class

Tags: java, junit4

I'm currently using a BaseTest class to do some basic test setup before each of my tests. For one of our testing applications, we pass the name of the test to the application by setting it via the driver. Something like this:

```
WebDriver driver = getDriver();
driver = appName.open(driver, "testName");
```

In the past, we've always done this within each test...

```
public class testClass extends BaseTest {

@Test
    public void TestAThing() throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    driver = appName.open(this.driver, "TestAThing");

    //do something
}

}
```

But I'm trying to set it up in our BaseTest class so that we can do this under a @BeforeEach annotation, and we don't have to do it per-test anymore. But, obviously, in order to do this I have to be able to get the name of the Test method that's running, not the name of my BaseTest method, and I'm a bit lost on how to do that. I know of getMethodName(), which obviously just grabs the name of the current method, so something like this:

```
public class BaseTest {

@BeforeEach
public void setupTest() {

String methodName = new Throwable()
                .getStackTrace()[0]
                .getMethodName();

driver = appName.open(driver, methodName);
}

}
```

sets `methodName = setupTest` where I need it to be set to `TestAThing`. Everything I've come up with so far relates to the @Rule annotation or TestRule, but those still need to be implemented at the test-level if I'm not mistaken. Does anyone have any ideas how to pull in this information for any test I throw at it using my `BaseTest` class?

Comment: You can use a `TestInfo` object to access the name of the test method, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56205943/how-to-print-the-to-be-executed-test-methods-name-in-beforeeach-method-in, but what is the problem you have? It looks like you already got the name. To create and use the `WebDriver` instance, you can use protected fields which will set the `WebDriver` instance in your `@BeforeEach` method for each unit test method.

Comment: The `@Rule` or the `TestInfo` param (depending on your junit version) does not need to be implemented on test level. You can add them in the BaseTest.

Comment: @ProgmanThe issue I had before was I was getting the BaseTest method name instead of my test method name.  `TestInfo` solved that problem for me, so thank you! If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

User Progman had the solution I was looking for in a comment. Posting it as the answer:

> You can use a `TestInfo` object to access the name of the test method, see [How to print the "to be executed" @Test method's name in "@BeforeEach" method in JUnit 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56205943/how-to-print-the-to-be-executed-test-methods-name-in-beforeeach-method-in), but what is the problem you have? It looks like you already got the name. To create and use the `WebDriver` instance, you can use protected fields which will set the `WebDriver` instance in your `@BeforeEach` method for each unit test method.